# ListView GroupingTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

I want GroupTemplate of listview control  to have different group names to be displayed . I am not able to use function call inside GroupTemplate tag . For example I want output like this

---

### Cat

Cat One

Cat Two

---

### Rat

Rat One

Rat Three

---

### Lizard

Lizard One

Lizard three

Lizard Four

Group names are not static. Its dynamic . Based on the data it should display the group name . How to do this ?

Comment: how to detect Group names?

Comment: GroupName is not mand in ListView